# Uniform Continuous R.V. - Optimization

Tags: probability, optimization, uniform-distribution

working on this problem:

> A road construction company needs to decide where to place an
>   emergency phone on a stretch of road of length L. Suppose that
>   accidents can happen uniformly at random on this stretch of the
>   road.Where should the phone be placed so that the expected distance
>   from an accident to the phone is minimized? I.e., you need to find f
>   such that E[|X - f|] is minimized.

Solution attempt:

So I understand that I need to graph out the P.D.F for this. Once I get the P.D.F, I can find the mean of the P.D.F, and then minimize E[|X - f|].
How would I approach finding the P.D.F of this problem? How would I minimize the expected value in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the phone is placed at position $f$, then 
$E [\vert X - f \vert ] = \int_{0}^{L} \vert X - f \vert dX$, which
is $\frac{1}{2} ( f^2 + L^2 - Lf )$.  By taking the derivative with respect to
$f$, we see that the minimum occurs when $f = L/2$.